# How can I design a cryptographically secure, key-dependent s-box?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, s-boxes

I would like to design a cryptographically secure, key-dependent s-box, but I am not sure how. Mainly, because I am unsure about the difference in design compared to a random s-box.

What is the difference between the methods of S-box construction of “key-dependent s-boxes” and “random s-boxes”?

Comment: You might find a few hints at [“Desirable S-box properties”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1297/12164) and/or [“S-box design criteria and random sboxes”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3237/12164).