# What are the standard properties of an S-Box

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, s-boxes

Apart form the following, what are the other properties of a good cryptographic Substitution box or the S-Box:

1. Changing one input bit should change about half of the output bits.
2. Each output bit should depend on every input bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Desirable S-box properties](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/desirable-s-box-properties) also, related [S-box design criteria and random sboxes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3237/18298)

Answer (score 1):

Another very common criteria for an S-box with $n$ input bits and $m$ output bits with $m\le n$ (as most commonly used S-boxes are) is that each of the $2^m$ output values should be reached for exactly (or at least near) $2^{n-m}$ input values.

The question's criterion 1 can be made strict and become the [Strict Avalanche Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect#Strict_avalanche_criterion). There are even stricter /higher-order versions. There also is the [Bit independence criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect#Bit_independence_criterion). The desirability of these properties depends on the overall design of the cryptographic construction using the S-box, and is not easy to assess.

More generally, S-boxes are typically optimized with use as part of a particular cryptographic construction in mind, aiming at improving it's overall resistance against cryptanalytic attacks, as pointed in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/177314).

Comment: Also relevant are the resistance to the various forms of linear and differential cryptanalysis...

Comment: @SEJPM: is there another property of S-boxes likely to improve resistance to linear or differential cryptanalysis mostly regardless of the cipher? No universal one not already mentioned in the question or this answer comes to mind.

Comment: I know that having a uniform differential probability (?; and the linear equivalent) is important for S-Boxes in the two standard designs with S-Boxes (i.e. Feistel and SPN). I'm not currently aware of other designs with S-Boxes and whether they'd use different metrics (e.g. MARS may do something weird?).